# paginator->links() results in Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination

Im making a proyect with Laravel 4.2, bootstrap and MySQL.
Right now im having the following problem.

I retrieve database records and then i show them using pagination. I do this in the same way for several pages, so i created a blade template to not repeat myself. The problem comes when i use the `links` method of the `Paginator`. With a null argument the method doesn´t throw any exception but it doesn´t work properly since the links always redirects you to the main page no matter where you are.

In the Laravel 4.2 docs the following is said:

> *If you would like to specify a custom view to use for pagination, you
>   may pass a view to the links method:*
>
> ```
> <?php echo $users->links('view.name'); ?>
> ```

But if i try to do something like this in my blade template:

```
{{ $products->links('client.pages.search_results') }}
```

I get the following exception:

**Method Illuminate\View\View::__toString() must not throw an exception**

**EDIT**

This is the `search_results` template:

```
@extends('client.layouts.client')
@section('content')

    @include('client.includes.products', ['header_title' => "Results for $search",
                                          'show_platform_icon' => true,
                                          'view_name' => 'client.pages.search_results'])

@stop
```

And this is the `products` template:

```
<div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">

        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-header">
            <h3>{{ $header_title }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse navbar-right">
            {{ Form::open(['class' => 'navbar-form']) }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" id="sorter" >
                    <option disabled selected>Order by</option>
                    <option value="{{ URL::route('index') }}/name/asc">Name asc</option>
                    <option value="{{ URL::route('index') }}/name/desc">Name desc</option>
                    @if(Auth::check())
                    <option value="{{ URL::route('index') }}/discount/asc">Discount asc</option>
                    <option value="{{ URL::route('index') }}/discount/desc">Discount desc</option>
                    @else
                    <option value="{{ URL::route('index') }}/price/asc">Price asc</option>
                    <option value="{{ URL::route('index') }}/price/desc">Price desc</option>
                    @endif
                </select>
            </div>
            {{ Form::close() }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul class="thumnails col-md-11">
            @foreach ($products as $index => $product)
            <li class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 thumbnail">
                <a href="#product">
                    {{ HTML::image($product->game->thumbnail_image_path, $product->game->name) }}
                </a>

                <div class="caption">
                    @if($show_platform_icon)
                    <a href="#platform" class="pull-left">
                        {{ HTML::image($product->platform->icon_path, $product->platform->name) }}
                    </a>
                    @endif
                    <a href="#product">
                        <div class="text-center">

                            @if(Auth::check() && $product->discount)
                            <h3>
                                {{ floatval($product->price * ((100 - $product->discount) / 100)) }} € 
                                <span class="label label-default">-{{ floatval($product->discount)}}%</span>
                            </h3>
                            @else
                            <h3>{{ floatval($product->price) }} €</h3>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
            {{ $products->links($view_name) }}
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us `client.pages.search_results`? I think the error is somewhere in that view.

Comment: I edited my question. You can appreciate i pass the view name to the products template in order to make it work dynamically.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `links('view')` works. The view you pass will be used to display the pagination links. To give you an idea, this is the default one: [slider-3.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider-3.php)

Comment: Ok, i see my error. Now i have to figure out why when i use ````links()```` it redirects me to the main page instead of staying in the actual page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How do the links in the rendered page look like? Should be something with `?page=1`

Comment: Yes, the page it´s like that. But i just realize the problem is related to the routes, the pagination works well, the problem is one of my routes. I hope to get it fixed soon. Again, thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Okay. Let me know if you need any help

Comment: I fixed the issue. I was screwing up the pagination process with one of my routes. The paginator was trying to access the page segment but the route was redirecting that request to the main page. I couldn't do it without your help.

Comment: Sure thing. I've added a little answer so you can accept it and we can all move on ;) Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the comments below the question*

I think you misunderstand how `links('view')` works. The view you pass will be used to display the pagination links. To give you an idea, this is the default one: [slider-3.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Pagination/views/slider-3.php)

> Ok, i see my error. Now i have to figure out why when i use links() it redirects me to the main page instead of staying in the actual page. Thanks a lot.

How do the links in the rendered page look like? Should be something with `?page=1`

*a few hours later...*

> I fixed the issue. I was screwing up the pagination process with one of my routes. The paginator was trying to access the page segment but the route was redirecting that request to the main page. I couldn't do it without your help.